# Asp.net: can not debug this problem: Sys.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: elements

Tags: asp.net

This is strange, that I have this problem:

> Sys.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name:
>   elements.

This problem only happens in IE.

Details:

- ScriptResource.axd = Line: 4868
- Code: 0 - Char: 12

Webpage error details

> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1;
>   Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR
>   3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; AskTbBT4/5.8.0.12304) Timestamp: Tue, 25 Jan 2011 11:24:42 UTC

Message:

> Sys.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name:
>   elements Line: 4868 Char: 12 Code: 0 URI:
>   http://asdfsdf/ScriptResource.axd?d=7NwOnZl2VMauVPybpy_0vvP2zsCf0g8YK4dd3SkNMq873HwvoDhnE7rPvjFZwFLM0&t=11e661nl.js

Comment: Can you show some code involving the parameter elements? The error says your elements variable is null or undefined. Show the line of code how you are getting elements?

Comment: Are you using any AJAX controls?  Ajax Control toolkit?  Third party ASP.NET AJAX controls?

Comment: I have the same problem. It's undeniably some combination of UpdatePanel and ajaxcontroltoolkit.

Answer (score 33):

Changing ScriptMode to Release fixed this for me.

`<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" ScriptMode="Release"></asp:ScriptManager>`

Answer (score 16):

I have the same problem...

It's undeniably a combination of UpdatePanel and AjaxControlToolkit...

**Edit:**

Didn't see how old this question was. Maybe it's not relevant anymore... But in my case I have encountered this problem now on two occations and found two different solutions. The first occation involved update panels, a modalpopupextender and a validationsummary control. The problemw was that the validationsummary didn't output a semicolon at the end of the generated javascript. The solution is to create your own mini-control that inherits from ValidationSummary and does this on pre-render:

```
    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreRender(e);

        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), this.ClientID, ";", true);
    }
```

Simply adds a semicolon to the javascript. That solved it.

I'm unsure if I was facing the same problem again now, but my problem-page again had updatepanels, ajaxcontrol toolkit controls (Modalpopupextender) and validaiton summaries. Because I had forgotten my previous solution, I tried another one I found on google; setting

```
ScriptMode="Release"
```

on my scriptmanager in my master page. This worked. Not sure whether I should be happy or not with this... Seems like the debug version spits out javascript that doesn't work when combined with some other asp.net controls.

Comment: i tried this, that error fixed, and new error showing "undefined is null or not an object" in srciptresource.axd in IE8

Comment: Thanks @UmaN You saved my day. But I suspect that the release mode is taking off the ability for the browser to debug. But, hay, my application now works. So I leave this for later to investigate.

Answer (score 5):

You will also get this error if you set Visible=False on the control specified in the CancelControlID of a ModalPopupExtender.  If you have a code path where you need to hide the CancelControlID, just be sure to set the CancelControlID = "" in that situation.  That was the problem I ran into...

Comment: Mine was on same control, but I had different names on cancelcontrolid and the actually cancel control.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that the error message does not specify any details about the problem.

Answer (score 2):

In Case you are using ReportViewer on the page this might help.

Set `compilation debug="false"` in web.config.

Answer (score 1):

Happend to me where I've created an update panel in a custom server control and did not use RenderControl() afterwards

```
protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
  myUpdatePanel.RenderControl(writer);
}
```